# "Пустая" страница вместо содержимого

Tags: java

Доброго времени всем. Назвал тему вот как-то так.
Собираю maven-ом javaee проект с сервлетом (если криво звучит - я новичок).
Вроде все собирается, в корне war-ника лежит index.jsp с содержимым, но как только октрываю ее в браузере - чистый лист. Файл неустой!

В чем проблема?

Comment: War-ник нужен.
Добавьте ссылку

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy218al0v1xgubr/root-1.0.war

кстати, нет хорошего мануала, как собирать правильно maven-ом проект с сервлетом? как из под идеи собрать и задеплоить через application.xml я знаю.

Answer (score 2):

http://devcolibri.com/1043/ - мануал по сборке war архива через мавен из под идеи.
По вопросу: задеплоил на своем гласфише твой варник, idex.jsp открылся нормально в соответствии с содержимым.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/root-1.0/helloworld

ты так открывал?
за ссылку спасибо!

Comment: я открывал через корень развернутого приложения http://localhost:8080/root-1.0   ,что приводит к вызову index.jsp если другая страница не задана как стартовая в web.xml, твое обращение я так понимаю уже к сервлету, и причину отсутствия вывода надо искать в коде сервлета, который ты не прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: У вас Servlet ничего в ответ не пишет:

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("D:/maven_servlet.txt");
    fileWriter.close();

Напишите чего-нибудь в *request.getWriter()* и браузер это покажет.

Ещё заметил, что в сборку .jar файлы попали, которые есть в самом GlassFish нужно исключить их из сборки. Они там ненужны, т.к. есть в папке lib/ на сервере.

Comment: ах, черт, точно! все отрабатывает в коде сервлета по обращению к нему! там создается по get-у файл и больше ничего.